# Sveltekit - OAuth - Endpoint redirect doesn't work properly

Tags: oauth, sveltekit

I'm trying to implement an oauth authentification in a sveltekit app. I'm currently trying to authenticate with Github.

The project architecture is as follows:

```
.src
├── app.css
├── app.html
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── components
│   └── ...
├── global.d.ts
├── hooks.ts
├── lib
│   └── ...
└── routes
    ├── index.svelte
    ├── __error.svelte
    ├── __layout.svelte 
    └── oauth
       └── github
           ├── callback.ts
           ├── login.ts
           └── logout.ts
```

`index.svelte` contains UI elements that call the endpoint at `login.ts`. `login.ts` then redirects to Github auth page.

Here is `index.svelte`:

```html
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ session }) {
        return {
            props: {
                user: session.user
            }
        };
    }
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export let user;
    console.log('Welcome', user);
</script>

<a href="/oauth/github/login">Connect with Github</a>
```

This is the endpoint `./src/routes/oauth/github/login.ts`:

```js
export async function get(): Promise<{ status: number, headers: { location: string } }> {

    const ghAuthURL = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize';
    const clientId = import.meta.env.VITE_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID;
    const sessionId = '1234';

    return {
        status: 302,
        headers: {
            location: `${ghAuthURL}?client_id=${clientId}&state=${sessionId}`
        }
    };
}
```

When I click on the "Connect with Github" link, I land on the error page of my app with a 404 error. This is the error I read on the 404 :

```
Error: Not found: /oauth/github/login
    at Renderer._get_navigation_result (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:807:11)
    at Renderer.update (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:626:38)
    at Renderer.handle_navigation (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:615:14)
    at Router._navigate (http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:292:23)
    at http://127.0.0.1:3000/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/internal/start.js:175:9
```

If I reload this error page, I land on github's auth page and I can connect.

What is it that I'm missing here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: sorry for asking here, can i know what you've put in the callback folder? My app is crashing at callback, and i didn't find any docs saying what I'm supposed to put in (with svelte)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to pass an attribute `rel="external"` to the anchor:

```html
<a href="/oauth/github/login" rel="external">Connect with Github</a>
```

Solution was found in the documentation :

> By default, the SvelteKit runtime intercepts clicks on  elements and bypasses the normal browser navigation for relative (same-origin) URLs that match one of your page routes. We sometimes need to tell SvelteKit that certain links need to be handled by normal browser navigation. Examples of this might be linking to another page on your domain that's not part of your SvelteKit app or linking to an endpoint.
>
> https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/a-options#rel-external